# cannot cast JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert the JSON data that i get back to an array so I can use the data in a listView.

I got the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonobject;
jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("example/url");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonobject;
if (jsonArray != null) {
   //do something with it
}
```

Note: I don't have any experience with Java. 
The method getJSONfromURL returns the JSON of the given URL that works just fine but the error is in `JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonobject;`

It gives the following error: cannot cast JSONObject to JSONArray
I've also tried this: `JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONObject)(JSONArray)jsonobject;`

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

So how can I cast my jsonobject to a normal array that I can use as data for my listView?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I'd take a look at the JSON you're getting back from the URL (and post it here if you can).  Are you sure it's an array?  Generally speaking, returning a top-level array is considered a security vulnerability.

Comment: This? http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html There is no class named `JSONFunctions`.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm using. Im sorry for the misunderstanding JSONFunctions is a class that I wrote myself.

Comment: If you expect an array, you can use `new JSONArray(String)`.

Comment: I'm indeed expecting an array

Comment: Alternatively, there's also a method `JSONObject.toJSONArray()` which will convert the object you already have to an array with the same keys.  This is probably less efficient than @xehpuk's solution, though.

Comment: @IanMcLaird how can I use your solution. I'm trying this right now: jsonobject.toJSONArray(jsonArray); where jsonArray is a JSONArray

Comment: Try `jsonobject.toJSONArray(jsonobject.names())`.

Answer (score 1):

A `JSONObject` is distinct from a `JSONArray`. If you try `new JSONObject("['test', 'array']")`, you will get a `JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`.

Try whether this works for you:

```
static JSONArray fromUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
    try (
        InputStream openStream = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(openStream);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    ) {
        if (!scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext()) {
            throw new EOFException("empty response");
        }
        return new JSONArray(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code throws an error at the last line return new JSONArray. Error: Unhandled exception:JSONException

Comment: @Bas In the sources I downloaded (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONException.java) it doesn't need to be handled because it `extends RuntimeException`. Then you have to handle the exception by adding a `catch`-clause or declare it to be thrown by putting it in the `throws`-clause (`throws IOException, JSONException`). But this is basic Java knowledge you should definitely acquire.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is like a Map in java. Key-value pair.
So, you should iterate like iterating a Map:

```
Iterator iterator = jsonobject.keys();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) iterator.next(); // assuming the key to be a String
    // You can put the key also if you want. But, It does not make any sense to do so.
    jsonArray.put(jsonobject.get(key)); 
}
```